# "avait raison/tort" or "a eu raison/tort"

Tags: expressions, temps-grammatical

> I think he was right/wrong.

Is it correct to translate this as

> (a) Je pense qu'il avait raison/tort.

or

> (b) Je pense qu'il a eu raison/tort.

I'm not sure if being right/wrong should be considered as an event (which would require the passé composé) or a state (which would require the imparfait). Or can it be either depending on the context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be both. For example, as a state (or context):

> Quand il nous a expliqué que ce ne serait pas possible, je pense qu'il avait raison.

As an event (or a step in the narration):

> On lui a dit de vendre la maison. Il a eu raison de ne pas le faire. Depuis les prix des logements ont flambé.

Comment: The first sentence feels more like an event to me than a state, since he is right about his explanation (thus, only about a specific thing at a specific time). Why is it a state/context to you?

Comment: You have to understand the first sentence as “I think he was right (all along) while he was explaining”. Interestingly you could also say "Il nous a expliqué que ce ne serait pas possible et je pense qu'il a eu raison” but the meaning is really distinct. In this case it can only be understood as “I think he was right (to choose) to explain it to us”.

Comment: It was a state in that it wasn't just a single event transpiring. The difference between the **imparfait** and the **passé composé**, you can see the different between whether it is stated as something which occurred continually or as a single event. @pi66